# How to drag a JavaFX node and detect a drop event outside the JavaFX Windows?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm implementing a TabPane that can be detached from the JavaFX window. When the tab pane is dragged outside of the window where it came from, I would like a new window to be created and the tab to be placed in that window.

I already implemented some methods using drag gestures to drag the tab between existing windows. However, I am not able to receive any mouse events or drag events when the mouse is moved outside of JavaFX scenes. Is this something possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad practice to have multiple windows? Just throwing that out, I may be wrong

Comment: Well just think about other software just like Notepad++ or even Photoshop. Don't you think it is helpful to be able to separate content displayed by the application into multiple windows that you can arrange however you want, on multiple screens? 
In Notepad++, the user can simply drag an editor tab and drag it outside the window to have another software window open with the tab present in it. I want to achieve something similar. (Even if notepad++ simply spawn another Notepad++ process and I want it to run in the same process)

Comment: I think the answer does a better job than I could, go check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for a mouse released event on the appropriate node (e.g. the tab's graphic). Check the screen coordinates using `MouseEvent.getScreenX()` and `MouseEvent.getScreenY()` and see if they lie outside the current window. If they do, create a new window, scene, and tab pane; remove the tab from the current tab pane and place it in the new one.

Here's a basic example with no frills (e.g. no user hints as to the fact that dragging is occuring), but it will give you the idea:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class DetachableTabExample extends Application {

    private int tabCount = 0 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Button newTabButton = new Button("New Tab");
        newTabButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            Label tabLabel = new Label("Tab "+(++tabCount));
            tab.setGraphic(tabLabel);
            tab.setContent(new TextArea());
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            tabLabel.setOnMouseReleased(me -> {
                Point2D mouseLoc = new Point2D(me.getScreenX(), me.getScreenY());
                Window window = tabPane.getScene().getWindow();
                Rectangle2D windowBounds 
                    = new Rectangle2D(window.getX(), window.getY(),
                                      window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
                if (! windowBounds.contains(mouseLoc)) {
                    tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);
                    Stage newStage = new Stage();
                    TabPane newTabPane = new TabPane();
                    newTabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(newTabPane));
                    newStage.setScene(scene);
                    newStage.setX(me.getScreenX());
                    newStage.setY(me.getScreenY());
                    newStage.setWidth(window.getWidth());
                    newStage.setHeight(window.getHeight());
                    newStage.show();
                }
            });

        });


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tabPane, newTabButton, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, this works. Thank you. 

I tried it before and could not get the MouseReleased event to fire. It seems like the MouseReleased event will not get fired once a DragAndDrop gesture is hapenning. The tab graphic setOnDragDetected method calls contentTab.getTabPane().startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);, then some data gets added to the DragBoard content. After, the MouseReleased does not get executed, any idea why?

Comment: I quickly tested that and it seemed to work, though the mouse coordinates seem a bit (OK, very) messed up. I didn't try any `onMouseDragOver` handlers (i.e. never called `acceptTransferModes(...)` on the `DragEvent`).

Comment: It looks like 

`Dragboard db = contentTab.getTabPane().startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
                clipboardContent.putString("Test");
                db.setContent(clipboardContent);` the `setContent` call will prevent any mouseevent from being recorded. Can you confirm you are seeing this? This is called from the OnDragDetected method.

Comment: That actually seems to work for me (though the mouse location is wrong). JDK 1.8.0_20 on Mac OS X 10.9.5. Once you start dealing with DnD outside the bounds of the JavaFX window, it is probably invoking native code and may be platform dependent.

Comment: Well thank you for your help. It really does seem there is something weird about this. As soon as I place something in the clipboard, the mouse event do not get registered. I guess I'll forget the built-in drag controls and will replace simply by mouse events.